# How to convert STACK_OF(X509) to DER in OpenSSL 1.1.0?

Tags: c, openssl, x509, der

While working on porting from OpenSSL 0.9.8 to 1.1.0, I have run into a missing function. The OpenSSL team has been busy cleaning up their code base, and one of the cleanups was to remove some ASN handling macros & functions. We used to be able convert from a `STACK_OF(X509)` certs to `DER` with the following bit of code:

*note: error handling removed for brevity of the example*

```
PyObject* get_der(STACK_OF(X509) *stack) {
    unsigned char* enc
    int len;
    enc = ASN1_seq_pack_X509(stack, i2d_X509, NULL, &len);
    return PyString_FromString(enc, len)
    }
```

This no longer links and the build process errors out with unresolved external symbol.

I've checked the 0.9.8 code base, and found that `ASN1_seq_pack_X509` was a macro.  After tracking into deeply nested macros, I discovered that my call above would finally look like this:

```
ASN1_seq_pack(X509, stack, i2d_X509, NULL, &len)
```

And `ASN1_seq_pack` no longer exists in OpenSSL 1.1.0.  So here's my question. How should one convert from `STACK_OF(X509)` to `DER`?

Comment: I understand the queston has been answered here: https://mta.openssl.org/pipermail/openssl-users/2016-July/004079.html